# Fill Null values in Data-Frame with Column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data-frame with 55 columns and 2 million rows having mix of categorical and numeric fileds. There are null/na values in the data-set. I want to fill Null values with Column names.

The data-set I have is:

```
  A     B    C   D  .....
  1     na   na  3  .....
  na    3    4   na .....
  ........................
```

The output the I am trying to get is:

```
  A     B    C   D  .....

  1     B    C   3  .....
  A    3    4    D .....
  ........................
```

I am trying to use :

`df.fillna(method='ffill')`

Is there another way?

Python:3.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with columns converted to `Series` by [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
df = df.fillna(df.columns.to_series())
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  B  C  3
1  A  3  4  D
```

EDIT: If categorical columns in DataFrame select these columns and append non exist values by [`cat.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html):

```
for c in df.select_dtypes('category'):
    df[c] = df[c].cat.add_categories(c)
df = df.fillna(df.columns.to_series())
```

Comment: Giving the traceback as "Filling values must be in categories"

Comment: @ShubhamBajaj - What is `print (df.info())`

Comment: My data-set is a mix of categorical and numerical values.

Comment: What is the function of df.select_dtypes('category') and df[c] = df[c].cat.add_categories(c)

Comment: @ShubhamBajaj - first are selected all categorical columns and then are appended columns to these columns - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#appending-new-categories), so possible replace missing values in catagorical columns, because value exist.